# provider for PayPal ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, paypal

I am using [Cordova PayPal plugin](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin). But, when I am trying to add it to a page, I am getting the following error :

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for PayPal! Error: No
>   provider for PayPal! at injectionError
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1510:86) at noProviderError
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1548:12) at
>   ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3049:19) at
>   ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3088:25) at
>   ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3020:25) at
>   ReflectiveInjector*.get (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:2889:21)
>   at AppModuleInjector.get (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:358:125)
>   at AppModuleInjector.getInternal
>   (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:507:55) at
>   AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3856:44) at resolveDep
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11318:45) Stack

any ideas?
also, do you have any suggestion for understanding providers and promises?

Answer (score 1):

In your app.module.ts, add the followings

import { PayPal, PayPalPayment, PayPalConfiguration } from '@ionic-native/paypal';

Under @NgModule section, look for providers and add 'Paypal' as shown below :

providers:[
    PayPal 
]